# How to avoid nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I am trying to speed up my code and I'm unsure how to go about it.

The code reads filenames (of images) from a CSV file, downloads the images from a google cloud bucket and saves it into a folder. Each image basically has 43 different duplicates (so you can imagine that one image is one person and there are 43 images of different body parts of this person).

```
import os
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("/Desktop/images_csv_file.csv")
os.makedirs("./data/image_folder/", exist_ok=True)
for person in df.person_id:
    for i in range(1, 44):
        if i < 10:
            os.system(f"sudo gsutil cp gs://[My_Bucket_name]/{person}_000{i}/image.png ./data/image_folder/{person}_000{i}.png")
        else:
            os.system(f"sudo gsutil cp gs://[My_Bucket_name]/{person}_00{i}/image.png  ./data/image_folder/{person}_00{i}.png")
```

From my understanding, using two for-loops leads to quadratic time complexity, which means that the code will be slow. But I can't think of a way to get rid of at least one of the for loops. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: use j as a count and increment it everytime the outer for loop runs. Also, make j=0 outside for loop instead of i

Comment: If you have 43N images, then you need 43N fetches.  And your bottleneck is almost certainly the network transfers, not your code.  By the way, you can use `{i:04d}` to do the zero-filled digits.  You don't need an if statement.

Comment: "From my understanding, using two for-loops leads to quadratic time complexity" this is false. Your code has linear time complexity.

Comment: In general you should try to avoid looping in pandas and numpy. They have lots of built-in methods that operate over the entire dataframe/array automatically, so you don't have to write explicit loops.

Comment: @Barmar true, although in this case, it seems pandas is merely being used to read in a column from a csv, and that information is being used to shell out to gsutil. So there really is no prospect of vectorization making a material difference here. That being said, it would probably be better to simply use the `csv` module here.

Comment: But just to reiterate, because it is very important to understand, "using two for-loops leads to quadratic time complexity" is *absolutely false*.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi, thank you for this. I'm not familiar with {i:04d}, is there a link you can share about this? Or the name of the concept and I can look it up.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hi, alright sure. I'll go back and read more about algorithmic complexity. Thanks for this.

Comment: I can think of two things to speed up this either use list comprehension ithis would increase the speed slightly but since the bottleneck is very probably not related to the looping itself, it would not gain much. the second option I would use would be multithreading. However I have never used it with commands like yours so I am not sure if it is doable. here is a link to a youtube video that helped me in the past with multithreading: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU

Comment: at the end of the video there is an  example similar to what you are trying to do